# How can I split the channels of a surround sound (7.1) to seperate output devices in windows?

Tags: windows, audio, surround-sound

I am looking to split the front, side, and rear channels of my motherboard's rear panel into separate output devices in windows. I've done this before on linux, using pulseaudio like in this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Splitting_front/rear, but I can't find how to do this in windows.

I am currently using Windows 10, version 20H2.

Comment: Add the **hardware specifications** to your post too.

Comment: Sorry, what are you looking for? Just the motherboard model?

Comment: Yep and other devices connected to those outputs too if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the **[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)** player on Windows and open up three its instances, then in every one go to the main menu on the following path **Audio->Audio Device** and set up the desired channel.

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for. I am wanting to get 3 separate output devices from the one combined output device. This is for all of my audio, not just a particular media.

Comment: Do you have any photo of those devices connected to each other?